# How to check convergence of $\int _1^{\infty }\:\left(\ln x\right)^p\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}dx,\,p>0$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Check convergence of  $\int _1^{\infty }\:\left(\ln x\right)^p\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}dx,p>0$

I tried , $$(\ln x)^p\frac{\sin x}{x}\le(\ln x)^p\frac{1}{x}$$

but $\int _1^{\infty }\:\left(\ln x\right)^p\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx$ is diverges when $p>0$
.

$\int _1^{b\:}\:\left(\ln x\right)^p\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx=\left[\dfrac{\left(\ln x\right)^{p+1}}{p+1}\right]_1^b$

$\int _1^{\infty }\:\left(\ln x\right)^p\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx=\lim _{x\to \infty }\dfrac{\left(\ln b\right)^{p+1}}{p+1}=\infty $

any another idea how to check if it convergence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $M>1$. Then integrating by parts,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_1^M\frac{(\ln x)^p\sin x}{x}dx
=\left[(\ln x)^p\frac{-\cos x}{x}\right]_1^M+\int_1^M\frac{(p-\ln x)(\ln x)^{p-1}}{x^2}\cos x\:dx
\end{align}
$$ the latter integral is absolutely convergent, since for some $A$, 
$$
\left|\frac{(p-\ln x)(\ln x)^{p-1}}{x^2}\cos x\right|\le \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}, \qquad x>A.
$$ By letting $M\to \infty$, the given integral is then *convergent*.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n= \int_{\pi n}^{\pi(n+1)}.$ When $n$ is even, $a_n$ is positive.  When $n$ is odd, $a_n$ is negative.  So the integral is equal to an alternating series.  Observe that $a_n$ is decreasing, and you have convergence by alternating series test.